# How to wait for a single task in Intel TBB in a task group and kill others?

Tags: c++, task, wait, intel, tbb

In Intel TBB, I'm trying to:
 1. Create a set of tasks
 2. Let them run
 3. When one of them finishes, I get some result out of it and kill the others.

How can I do that ? I can see only API to wait for all not just single...

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The task that finishes can store its result in a known place and cancel the group with `task::self().cancel_group_execution()`.  The `wait_for_all()` will then become unblocked and that thread can load the result from the known place.
https://www.threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/tbb_userguide/Cancellation_Without_An_Exception.html shows how to use `cancel_group_execution()`.